# AudioWorklet modify microphone input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, audio-worklet

I would like to modify the microphone input in real-time using an `AudioWorklet`, in a chrome extension.

For a simple example, I just want to transmit an oscillator wave, like in [this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DqYuLBrpWCo5Ks75?preview), where one is transmitted to the `output`.

I first create the worklet:

```
await audioCtx.audioWorklet.addModule(WORKLET_PATH);
this.worklet = new AudioWorkletNode(audioCtx, 'oscillator');
this.worklet.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

Then, I connect a microphone:

```
this.microphoneStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});
this.microphone = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(this.microphoneStream);

console.log('microphone', this.microphone.mediaStream.getTracks()[0].label);
this.microphone.connect(this.worklet as AudioWorkletNode);
```

And in the example plnkr, in `processor.js`, instead of modifying the output I modify the input, setting line 15 to be:

```
const output = inputs[0];
```

But unfortunately, that does not modify the microphone. If I just playback the microphone audio, I can't hear the oscillator